# How to convert overlapping ranges to contiguous ranges?

Tags: r, data.table

I have overlapping ranges like this

**data**

```
G S E
o 10 15
o 13 20
r 20 28
r 25 33
```

I am trying to convert this into table shown below.

```
G S E
o 10 12
o 13 19
r 20 24
r 25 33
```

I have been trying use `ifelse` condition and `data.table` `shift` to access values from next row for comparison, but did not succeed yet. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: @akrun I am quite new to data.table. I am not sure if this is the right way to go here is my attempt `data[ , F := ifelse(E > shift(S, 1L, type="lag"), shift(S, 1L, type="lag")-1, E),by = 1:row(data)]`

Comment: For overlaps, you can check `foverlaps` from data.table

Comment: @akrun with `foverlaps` I think I can find the overlapping ranges but how can I modify the range coordinates to make them continuous

Comment: By looking at your data, all you need to do is simply `df$E[-nrow(df)] <- df$S[-1] - 1`